# How to resolve AWS REST API-method circular dependency in CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I'm creating an AWS API Gateway that exposes a GET method on its root.
My GW:
`

```
MyApiGateway:
  Type: "AWS::Serverless::Api"
  DependsOn: GetRequest
  Properties:
    Name: !Sub my-api-${EnvironmentName}
```

The DependsOn is according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-deployment.html#aws-resource-apigateway-deployment--examples): "If you create an AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi resource and its methods (using AWS::ApiGateway::Method) in the same template as your deployment, the deployment must depend on the RestApi's methods"

My method:

```
GetRequest:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
  Properties:
    AuthorizationType: AWS_IAM
    HttpMethod: GET
    RestApiId: !Sub my-api-${EnvironmentName}
    ResourceId: !GetAtt MyApiGateway.RootResourceId
```

`
And it depends on the GW again according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html#cfn-apigateway-method-resourceid): "The ID of an API Gateway resource. For root resource methods, specify the RestApi root resource ID, such as { "Fn::GetAtt": ["MyRestApi", "RootResourceId"] }."

This CloudFormation template cannot be built due to the circular dependency.
How can I expose a GET method on the API GW's root path without causing this circular dependency?

I tried removing the DependsOn section, and got the error "No integration defined for method"